# Can I use num_tokens as load factor in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

If you run cassandra on machines with different sizes of hard disk (e.g. one with one TB, another with 2TB), can I use num_tokens as load factor?
I want to reduce the risk of one node running out of disk space and balance the usage of disk on different machines.

I know, the more data one node collects, the more probable it might become a hotspot. Apart from that, which other considerations do I need to take care of? Which limits or practical restrictions exist for the number of nodes?
Can I change the number of nodes later if disk space changes without trouble?

I would appreciate some advice on that topic because I have not found much information about that in google or at the website of cassandra.

EDIT: numnodes replaced by num_tokens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to [num_tokens](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__num_tokens) settings? Yes, you can use a different number of tokens based on the hardware resources. Nodes with a larger number of tokens will see higher load and disk usage. Once set, the num_tokens setting cannot be changed at a later point without decommissioning the node.